# The Workplace is hitting the big ten year mark!

Tags: discussion

## The Workplace is turning ten years old!

A blog post announcing our ten year anniversary will soon be posted on the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/)!

### Original Announcement Post

As other sites have done before us The Workplace StackExchange is turning ten years old next quarter, and SE staff have reached out asking us for a brief summary to be featured in the blog so we thought we'd see what users would like the text to say.

If you would like to see the sort of things others have said you can look at the Q1 edition [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/16/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-site-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-q1-2022/).

As you can see some sites have also volunteered a few "interesting questions" from the sites' archives so any suggestions there would also be appreciated.

Comment: 10 years is pretty cool, I've definitely learned an enormous amount both about the workplace and other societies resolution strategies from the people here.

Comment: Wow, 10 years? Time flies when you are having fun!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Indeed! I was startled to discover that I've been on the site for over 5 years now.

Answer (score 6):

Figured I'd give it a go since we would like to have something to share with the community at large. Feel free to submit your own text or suggest edits in the comments or a new answer!

> While many people browse Stack Exchange at work, the Workplace has the unique distinction of also covering all things work related. Professionalism may be the name of the game, but how do you handle coworkers who have [a thing or two](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44738) to learn in that area? What if you want to bring a literal [rubber duck](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83451/can-i-talk-to-my-rubber-duck-at-work) to the office? And how do you approach that all-important question of [asking for a raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025)? The Workplace is there to help you navigate those tricky situations. And hey, it's not goofing off when it's Workplace-related, right?

We're checking with the community team if we'll be able to link to the questions in the post itself. If not, they'll just be three numbered links next to our top tag. Which for now is still professionalism, though "interviewing" is hot on it's tail which will ruin my wordplay...

Comment: I like it... it's a classic!

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the "rubber duck" question with something more general. That one is too software-specific. The "thing or two" probably isn't the best choice either. I don't feel questions like that are representative of The Workplace.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The rubber duck is admittedly there to cater to the mostly IT-focused audience who'd end up on that blog. Agreed that the professionalism questions isn't the best. I'd sooner replace it with something else but I didn't really find any good high quality questions around unprofessional colleagues. Perhaps something management-related might be a better fit? Feel free to link other good questions that might showcase us better! And that goes for everyone of course!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere do you have any suggestions for replacement questions? This is just a draft at this point.

Answer (score 0):

[This is our highest scoring question.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93696/is-it-unethical-for-me-to-not-tell-my-employer-i-ve-automated-my-job)

We don't really have a typical sort of question here that I can think of.